# C++ Assignment Constructor Valgrind Errors

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

I'm trying to create my own vector for practicing purposes. All went fine, but now I wanted to test the vector which holds objects that allocates memory, too.

My problem lays in the assignment constructor of that class (1), that were called in the constructor of the test vector.

test_vec.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_VEC
#define TEST_VEC

#include <cstddef>

template<class T>
class vector
{
public:
    explicit vector(size_t count, const T& value)
        : m_size(count)
        , m_capacity(count)
        , raw_data(static_cast<T*>(operator new(count * sizeof(T))))
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            raw_data[i] = value; //(1) Calls the assignment constructor
        }
    }

    ~vector()
    {
        //clearing objects not implemented yet
        operator delete(raw_data);
    }
private:
    size_t m_size;
    size_t m_capacity;
    T* raw_data;
};

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "test_vec.h"

class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass(size_t number) {
        testMem = new size_t[10];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            testMem[i] = 0;
        }
        testMem[1] = number;
    }
    TestClass(const TestClass& other) {
        testMem = new size_t[10];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            testMem[i] = other.testMem[i];
        }
    }
    TestClass& operator=(const TestClass& other) {        
        if (this != &other) {
            //I know this is not exception safe at the moment
            delete[] testMem; //(2) delete earlier assigned memory 
            testMem = new size_t[10];

            for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                testMem[i] = other.testMem[i];
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    ~TestClass() {
        delete[] testMem;
    }
    size_t number() const {
        return testMem[1];
    }
private:
    size_t* testMem = NULL;

};

int main() {
    TestClass t1(4); //(4)
    TestClass t2(3);

    t1 = t2;

    vector<TestClass> vec_TestClass(1, TestClass(3)); //(3)
}
```

Everything went fine. But valgrind complains here at (3) with "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised values". That is correct because testMem is not initialised in the moment I want assign the object. But when I comment delete out (2) I get a memory leak from (4). Thisis correct, too.

How can I solve this problem, so that both cases are handled?

Thanks and greetings

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as an 'assignment constructor'. I understand that you might want to mess with uninitialised memory, but you still need to call proper constructors. The easiest way in your case would be to use `std:::uninitialised_fill_n`

```
#include <memory>

explicit vector(size_t count, const T& value)
    : m_size(count)
    , m_capacity(count)
    , raw_data(static_cast<T*>(operator new(count * sizeof(T))))
{
    std::uninitiliased_fill_n(raw_data, count, value);
}
```

Also note that you vector destructor also needs to destroy any objects it has constructed.

Comment: For destruction of elements since C++17, [`std::destroy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy) is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Why this `static_cast<T*>(operator new(count * sizeof(T)))` rather than a proper `new T[count]`? You're never actually creating any `T`s! `TestClass` is not trivial, either, so it does need to be constructed. Valgrind appears to know this.

`operator new` and `operator delete` are for allocators, not for users. They just create a block of memory, no objects. Use `new` and `delete` (or, in real code, standard containers!).

Furthermore, your `vector` class has no copy constructor. So, any copy of `vector` has an uninitialised, invalid `raw_data` member pointer. That's not a problem in your testcase but is one in general.

Also, there's no such thing as an assignment constructor. Either you construct, or you assign!

Comment: You cannot use `new` expression here, since `T` might not have default constructor (it is not required by the Standard for `std::vector` elements). One has to use `operator new` and then construct elements in place by _placement new_ (using copy/move constructor). Either manually, or via allocators or `std::uninitialized_xxx` functions.

Comment: @DanielLangr Oh yeah, fair enough

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I think it is called assignment operator. The error is that the TestClass has no default constructor. I fixed that and everything went fine. I replaced new and delete operators with the rihgt functions. I stripped down my vector for this little example. The copy constructor also.

Thanks. The hint that I need the default constructor was the solution.

Comment: No, it was not the solution. You have undefined behavior in your code independently of whether vector's value type has or hasn't default constructor. As others pointed out, you need to create objects of type `T` in the uninitialized memory before you can assign them. Much better solution is to construct the elements in place using copy/move constructor (it is generally more efficient and there is no need for default constructor then).

Comment: Indeed, unless a default constructor makes sense for that class (and, if so, why did it not already have one?) this seems like a backwards step. If it does, though, then great!

Comment: Yes. The adding of a default constructor was a quick workaround. Now I use the solution with uninitialized_xxx functions.